# How to configure GWT stacktrace deobfuscator under Tomcat?

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

I want to configure remote logging service with deobfuscate option. I know that symbol maps by default are generated in /WEB-INF/deploy/MODULNAME/symbolMaps folder and GWT remote logger implementation (RemoteLoggingServiceImpl) uses StackTraceDeobfuscator, which needs symbolMaps dir to work. I think that RemoteLoggingServiceImpl should automatically set right path to symbolMaps directory, but in debug mode I find out that setSymbolMapsDirectory method is not invoke on RemoteLoggingServiceImpl. To resolve that problem I manually invoke that method using "proxy":

```
public class ConfigurableRemoteLoggingServiceImpl extends RemoteLoggingServiceImpl {

@Override
public void init(final ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    final String symbolMapsDirectory = config.getInitParameter("symbolMapsDirectory");
    setSymbolMapsDirectory(symbolMapsDirectory);
}
}
```

and in web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pl.dandelite.empik.sdl.manager.server.service.ConfigurableRemoteLoggingServiceImpl</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
          <param-name>symbolMapsDirectory</param-name>
          <param-value>C:/symbolMaps</param-value>
      </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>remoteLogging</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sdlconsole/remote_logging</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and during compile define dir using -extra parametr

This solution works, but only when I set absolute path to symbolMaps directory, what is little bit impractical ;)

Now my question is: What is right way to configure RemoteLoggingServiceImpl with StackTraceDeobfuscator on Tomcat ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. You are saying that the servlet init method is not called during debug? By debug, do you mean dev-mode? I have a similar implementation of init (see answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I setup the symbol directory:

```
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    // Synchronized so that in a multi-module deployment, there are no conflicts.
    synchronized (RemoteLoggingServiceImpl.class) {
        // Initialize SLF$j bridge logging to redirect jul logs to slf4j. We remove any
        // default loggers to ensure logging doesn't happen to stdout or stderr.
        java.util.logging.Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            rootLogger.removeHandler(handler);
        }
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }

    String moduleName = config.getInitParameter("module.name");
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(moduleName)) {
        _logger.error("No module name defined. Please set the module.name servlet init "
                + "parameter to point to the GWT module and enable extra symbolMaps at "
                + "/extra/<module name>/symbolMaps in the servlet context to facilitate "
                + "deobfuscation of stack traces.");
    } else {
        String path = config.getServletContext().getRealPath(
                "/WEB-INF/deploy/" + moduleName + "/symbolMaps/");

        if (path != null) {
            setSymbolMapsDirectory(path);
        }
    } // end else.
}
```